Film with a spaceship crew fighting a cyborg who can rebuild themselves. Girl main character
This was a movie from the 90s, I think. It takes place in space on a spaceship. The crew is fighting against a cyborg who can rebuild if damaged. I remember at the end they blow up the ship and escape with a pod. There is a girl who is the main character.

Did you see it in theaters? On VHS? On TV?

Was the film in English? Japanese? Russian? Did it seem to be subtitled or dubbed?

Do you remember anything about ethnicity of the characters?

People: please don't knee-jerk downvote. This question is only 12 min old at the time of this writing. Give this (new) user time to add more details, if they are missing.

Hey, thanks it's my first time here. It was on the tele, and English. The actor were Americans. I was younger so it was in between 97 and 2000. Am not sure but one of the main actor was Micheal biehn, not sure. The only thing I do remember is the thé vilain is a human turn to a machine or cyborg who can fix it's self and the end they blow up the ship

Could this be Saturn 3? Killer robot, female lead (Farrah Fawcett, no less) space station, escape pod, explosion.




I will have a look. It look like so
